# Can we create instance of our model class in KIF test class

Tags: ios, swift, kif

In KIF testing framework, in KIF acceptance class, can we create an instance of our controller class or model class to get the functions and views from that specific class? Or is the accessibility label the only way to identify the view? And if the latter is the only option, then how can we get access to our model class in KIF test class?

Comment: I tried to punctuate this a little better. Could you review this in case I changed the meaning of the question?

Comment: No meaning doesn't changed.Thanks for punctuating this a little better. But my problem still persists as how to get access to modal class in my KIF test class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can access anything in your host app.

Also, for your later choice, you can put a weak reference in your view to the model ..

But a notice is that, if you want to modify some static variable or access then, that bundle must be a singleton - Not two copies (one for test, one for app).